# What is wrong with below function although both variables are already declared?

Tags: javascript

```js
 function foo() {
      this.baz = "baz";
      console.log(this.bar + " " + baz);
    }
    
    var bar = "bar";
    var baz = new foo(); // "undefined undefined"
    
    foo(); // "bar baz"
```

When i am running above function the output is `undefined undefined`. I don't understand why the values of both `bar` and `baz` are not showing in console log.

but when i am calling simply `foo()`, output in console is `"bar baz"`. why is like that?

Comment: `this.bar` doesn't exist, but `this.baz` does - typo? Anyway, while the function is executing, `baz` hasn't been assigned the same function's return value (or, in this case, the new object instance) yet.

Comment: Shouldn't `(this.bar + " " + baz)` be `(this.baz + " " + bar)`?

Comment: First, `this` will be new instance being created which don't have `bar` on it, second, `baz` is actually `undefined`.

Comment: Why would you *expect* this to work in the first place and *what* do you expect it to output exactly?

Comment: there is no `bar` property and `baz` variable.

Comment: @mplungjan, I think this should have been closed as a typo instead

Comment: @Rajesh I sort of agree, but the duplicate gives much more information which is sorely needed in this case or we will see another question in a minute

Answer (score 1):

`this.bar` is not defined, perhaps you meant `this.baz`?

`baz` is not defined because you are printing within the constructor function. while it's running the global `baz` variable is still undefined.

Comment: no, i meant `this.baz` only.

Answer (score -1):

Its easy. Just because you have problem with scopes.

See...

```js
function foo() {
      this.baz = "baz";
      console.log(bar + " " + this.baz);
    }
    
    var bar = "bar";
    var baz = new foo();
```

Comment: Please do not answer a typographical mistake

Comment: @Rajesh How do you know that this is typographical  mistake ? and do you know the difference between  a typographical mistake and wrong syntax ?

Comment: @ANS `Wrong syntax`??? Please explain. I might have misunderstood question. Also I was not the voter on your answer.

Comment: @Rajesh I don't really care about votes. Have them enough and Wrong Syntax is writing writing `baz` instead of `this.baz`

Comment: @ANS I still don't see how that is wrong syntax. Isn't this what is called as typographical mistake? Typing `this` in front of wrong variable

Comment: Both you're right. @Rajesh means that he just made a typo with `bar` and `baz`, but @ANS means that he did not write `this.baz`.